# Python - html2text write to file

Tags: python

I have text files which contain html tags which I want to remove using html2text with Python:

```
import html2text
html = open("textFileWithHtml.txt").read()
print html2text.html2text(html)
```

My question is how can I write the output to a .txt file ? (I want to create the new text file without the html elements -- the file does not previously exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open another file for writing.

```
import html2text
html = open("textFileWithHtml.txt")
f = html.read()
w = open("out.txt", "w")
w.write(html2text.html2text(f).encode('utf-8'))
html.close()
w.close()
```

Comment: You should probably use with

Comment: I am getting the following error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "removeHtml.py", line 4, in <module>
    w.write(html2text.html2text(html))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 5040: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: try `w.write(html2text.html2text(html).encode('utf-8'))` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work. I get an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "removeHtml.py", line 5, in <module>
    html.close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close' but when I put comments on html.close() it works.

Answer (score 3):

You should open a file and write to it.

```
import html2text

# Open your file
with open("textFileWithHtml.txt", 'r') as f_html:
    html = f_html.read()

# Open a file and write to it
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html2text.html2text(html).encode('utf-8'))
```

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects.

And it is more pythonic too.
See more information for files reading / writing files : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

---

**Edit**

If you have issues with encoding, try using `.encode('utf-8')`. I've added it in my code snipped. Look for python unicode if you have issues regarding this (https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: I am getting this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "removeHtmlPrintToFile.py", line 4, in <module>
    w.write(html2text.html2text(html))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 5040: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Thanks d6bels you and Avinash both got it right with the encoding.